# Horizontal percent total stacked bar chart with labels on each end

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple data frame which has the probabilities that an id is real and fake, respectively:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(id = "999", real = 0.7, fake = 0.3)
```

I know that I can show this as a horizontal bar chart using the code below:

```
dat %>% 
  gather(key = grp, value = prob, -id) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = prob, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

But I was wondering if there was a way to show this in the same way as shown below, with the class labels and probabilities on either end of the bar chart?

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward, maybe somewhat cheeky workaround is to re-define your 0.

I added a few calls that are not strictly necessary, but make it look closer to your example plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(id = "999", real = -0.7, fake = 0.3) # note the minus sign!

dat %>% 
  gather(key = grp, value = prob, -id) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = prob, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = stringr::str_to_title(paste0(grp, " (", as.character(100*abs(prob)), "%)"))), 
            hjust = c(1,0))+
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = .1,
        plot.margin = margin(r = 3, l = 3, unit = "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this fully answers the question but I think it will improve the plot, can you try it out?

```
dat %>% 
  gather(key = grp, value = prob, -id) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = prob, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous("Proportion") +
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: that code is not working - first, a `+` is missing, and using scale_fill_identity naturally does not work with an unknown color "real"